# dynamics ax : Push Customized form to All users

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Recently, I was troubleshooting an issue related to user settings. There was a requirement to migrate the user settings from one environment to another.

There is an AX 2009 form which users make their own personalisations to, moving some of the fields around, or perhaps adding other fields (via the right click->setup functions) , so that unnecessary fields are hidden.
I have saved that form , so that it is available for me , but when i migrate the form to another environment  i notice that the new user don't have any change on the form.

As we all know, User related setups for queries, forms, reports etc are stored in SysLastValue table. This is a system table and can't be accessed directly through AOT.

Comment: It is unclear what your specific question is. Also, your question title (push customized form to all users) does not match your first sentence (requirement to migrate user settings to another environment). As far as accessing the kernel table `SysLastValue`, you can open a table browser to view and edit the data. You can also write code to interact with the data. You cannot change the structure of the table though. I guess I would take a look at the save, load and retrieve from user functions in the personalization form to learn how to move user settings.

Comment: what i'm looking for is when i save my form personalization i want to share it between others users ,when a user click on button "retrieve from user" he found name of my customization but my personalization are not aplied to the form in her session the same thing when i try to export xpo project to another environment. i 'm trying to copu usage data from user to user but I haven't yet to successfully

Comment: I do not understand your reference to a xpo project export. A xpo file does not contain user personalizations of a form. What I get from your comment is that the "Retrieve from user" function does not work for you. Did you debug it? Did you test it with different users and forms? Can you tell us which form you have personalized in what way?

Comment: @FH-Inway : For the xpo file just for  export project and testing personalization from environment test  to another environment .For the "Retrieve from user"  function he load all user customazation but when i select one of them my form don't have any change. i'm working for Vendtable Form

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you are trying to achieve:

http://axaptian.blogspot.md/2010/01/savecopy-filtersqueriesinquires-to.html

Basically, it allows to save custom filters and queries and pass it to other users. Although it copies only queries, I am sure it can be modified to copy any usage data.